# Get user input and store into array with custom length (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, input

I am writing a code that takes a number as the array length and asks the user to input values into it. The problem with my code is that when I print out the values of the array it would give out random values that were never part of the array in the first place. I looked online for all of this and the code just seems right to me but for some reason it is not printing out properly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x, input;

    

    cout<<"Enter the number of values: "<< endl;
    cin >> x;

    int arr[x];

    cout<<"Enter the values: "<< endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cin>>input;

        input = arr[i];
    }

    cout<<" "<< endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cout<< arr[i]<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: not `input = arr[i];` but `arr[i] = input;`

Comment: `int arr[x];` is not standard C++. Just use `std::vector` for variable length array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line of yours-

```
input = arr[i];
```

**Here you are assigning the value of *arr[i]* to the *input* variable**, in this way you never actually set the value of arr[i] and which is why it stores a grabage value. You should change it to-

```
arr[i] = input;
```

Or may be you don't need to use *input* variable, you can do something like-

```
cin >> arr[i]; // it will just take the value and assign it to arr[i]
```